# Push message in Samsung Tizen push server using C, winsock(windows)

Tags: c, json, push, winsock, tizen

I want to send messages to the "Samsung Tizen push server".

I made same program using C#, WebRequest.
The program works very well.

Now I'm making the same program in C.
But the program does not seem to communicate properly.

This is C# program source.

```
private string SendTizenPushServer()
{
    string resultStr;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://apkorea.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8;";
    request.Headers.Add(string.Format("appID:xxxMy_appIDxxx"));
    request.Headers.Add(string.Format("appSecret:xxxMy_appSecretxxx"));
    var postData = new {
        regID = "xxxMy_regIDxxx",
        requestID = "0000001",
        message = "alertMessage=Hi",
    };

    string contentMsg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
    Debug.WriteLine("contentMsg = " + contentMsg);

    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contentMsg);
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    try
    {
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        resultStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Debug.WriteLine("response: " + resultStr);
        reader.Close();
        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        resultStr = "";
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

This program work result :

```
"{\"results\":[{\"regID\":\"xxxMy_regIDxxx\",\"requestID\":\"0000001\",\"statusCode\":1000,\"statusMsg\":\"Success\"}]}"
```

And the Tizen equipment also received the data as normal.

My problem is the C program. This is my C program source using winsock2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define MAXLINE 4096

SSIZE_T SendTizenPushServer()
{
    // newtwork value
    char sendData[MAXLINE + 1], recvData[MAXLINE + 1], data[MAXLINE + 1];
    SSIZE_T n;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET fcmSocket;
    struct hostent *hostent;
    SOCKADDR_IN sockAddr;

    // samsung push server host name
    char *hname = "apkorea.push.samsungosp.com";

    // network setting
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if ((hostent = gethostbyname(hname)) == NULL) 
    {
        printf("gethostbyname error for host: %s:",hname);
        return 0;
    }
    fcmSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (fcmSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Socket failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    memset(&sockAddr, 0, sizeof(sockAddr));
    sockAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*hostent->h_addr_list));
    sockAddr.sin_port = htons(8090);

    if (connect(fcmSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Connect failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    sprintf(data,
        "{\"regID\":\"xxxMy_regIDxxx\","
        "\"requestID\":\"00000001\","
        "\"message\":\"alertMessage=Hi\""
        "}\r\n");

    sprintf(sendData,
        // Header 
        "POST /spp/pns/api/push HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "appID: xxxMy_appIDxxxx\r\n"
        "appSecret: xxxxMy_appSecretxxxx\r\n"
        "Host: %s:8090\r\n"
        "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
        "Content-Length: %d\r\n\r\n"
        // Data
        "%s", hname, strlen(data), data);

    printf("send data : \n%s\n\n", sendData);

    send(fcmSocket, sendData, strlen(sendData), 0);

    while ((n = recv(fcmSocket, recvData, MAXLINE, 0)) > 0)
    {
        recvData[n] = '\0';
        printf("recv : %s\n\n", recvData);
    }

    closesocket(fcmSocket);
    WSACleanup;

    return n;
}
```

There is no response when running the program.
There is even no error response.

If appID or RegID was wrong, I got a message that it was wrong in C# program.
But There is no response in C program.

What is the problem? Please help me. T.T

Comment: Both sprintf() and send() return a value.  You should check both, and preferably use snprintf() to prevent any possible send buffer overflow.

Comment: Debug line by line to find error point and check different return value to ensure that command working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you have already checked this guide thoroughly.

[Push Server Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/messaging/push-server?langswitch=en)

I'm adding some Checklist from my end, Might be of help.

1) Log/Print the 'final JSON Request to send' from C# Code.
 Also Log/Print the 'final JSON Request to send' from C Code. And Compare them letter by letter. ( I guess You might have done this several times already)

2) Create a local server and send request from both C# and C Code to that server. In this way, you can ensure both codes are hitting with same request body/config.

3) As there's a long list for [Handling Error Codes](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/messaging/push-server?langswitch=en#error_codes) and you are receiving none of them, There's a possibility that the Tizen Push Server is not being Hit by your server while using the C code.